# error while running the injector topolgy in strom crawler

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, nimbus

i am using follwing resources with their versions given

apache storm 1.2.3

storm crawler 1.16

zookeeper 3.6.1

elasticsearch 7.5.0

when i try to inject urls into my elasticsearch db through the given readme command-
"
storm jar target/crawler-1.16.jar org.commoncrawl.stormcrawler.news.CrawlTopology -conf $PWD/conf/es-conf.yaml -conf $PWD/conf/crawler-conf.yaml $PWD/seeds/ feeds.txt"

it shows the following errors-> 
[

error-1->
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?

error-2->
org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing getLeader

]

this is my storm.yaml file configs->

[

storm.zookeeper.servers:

```
 - "localhost"
```

storm.local.dir: "/home/zathura/Desktop/apache-storm-1.2.3/data"

nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]

supervisor.slots.ports:

- 6700
- 6701
- 6702
- 6703

nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size: 20480000

]

and also my storm ui is not showing the required output page

[my storm ui screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd0cm.png)

Comment: are the storm and zookeeper services running? anything in the logs?

Comment: yes they were running  and this is in the nimbus log   " o.a.s.b.BlobStoreUtils timer [ERROR] Could not download blob with key crawler-1-1591193672-stormconf.ser"                                       
This was the other error-                                                                                        
"java.lang.RuntimeException: No nimbus leader participant host found, have you started your nimbus hosts?

Comment: the second error is probably the result of the first one. Turn the topology and the Storm services and ZK off, delete the data directory of ZK, restart it all?

Comment: thanks julien, that helped